# How to compress data using client side scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a problem while transferring data from client side to back-end. If transfer data is more then its taking more time to send the request to back-end. So, I thought if i can compress the data, then it will take less time.

Is there any compression technique or method is available in the front end side using javascript or jquery.